# Why is there a gate-source short on a PMOSFET (DCDC circuit attached)

Tags: pcb, voltage-regulator, short-circuit, powermosfet, dielectric-breakdown

I am a beginner in power supply units. I got a failed DCDC regulator board and confirmed a gate - source short in a PMOSFET (about 2 ohms in both directions). As far as I know, this board is a power regulator with 28VDC input and 28VDC output. Here is the reverse circuit. My questions are:

1. Is there an error in my reverse? I don't understand why the output circuit (red circle) is connected to L2, shouldn't it be connected to L3/L4?
2. Why is there a gate-source short on a PMOSFET (M2)? The drain-source still has diode characteristics, while the gate-drain was measured normal.
3. How should I modify the circuit to make it work?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
[image: DC Regulator]

Comment: The schematic doesn’t seem to be complete and looks to have errors. At a guess it looks like a classic boost converter, but there is a diode missing. As to why the mosfet failed as it did, seems the gate oxide failed and shorted the gate to the source. Why do you think that it should fail differently?

Comment: Thanks Carman! I could be wrong as I have no experience with the DCDC combo. I thought it was a regulator since the input and output are both 28VDC. also, the switches and diodes seem different compared to the boost converter? I have double checked the board and there does not seem to be a diode missing. I still don't understand why the output circuit (the red circle) is connected to RTN_IN.

Comment: For the gate - source short in the MOSFET, I should mention that there are also some black burn marks around the MOSFET. I think this indicates some thermal damage. How can I determine the root cause of the oxide failure? ESD? overvoltage or current in the circuit?

Comment: To me it looks more like a low frequency PWM regulator, but there are too many errors to be sure. Check R209, if this fails, the gate voltage of M1-M3 will be too high.

Comment: Thanks Jens! I measured R209 and it's 510 ohms, which is consistent with the mark of 511 on it.

Comment: Corrected some errors, updated with new schematic. Does it make more sense this time? Still don't understand the part in the red circle.

Comment: Please check the position/connections of D1&D4. A FRED would be an odd choice for a reversal protection. Apropos: *reverse circuit* is to read *reverse engineered*?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. What I meant was that I couldn't find the schematic or documentation for the pcb, so I have to reverse engineer it. I have checked the connection of D1 and D4 and they appear to be correct.